# Where to get Toshiba monitor driver software for MacBook Pro running OS 10.7.4

Tags: mac, osx-lion, display, external-display

I am trying to connect my MacBook Pro running OS 10.7.4 to a Toshiba monitor. Where can I get  the necessary driver software?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a driver or any software for a monitor to work. Unless you have a touchscreen monitor, for instance.

As long as you have the right **hardware** connection, you're good to go.

If you don't know what connectors you're dealing with:

The MacBook Pros from 2008 till now all have **Mini DisplayPort** ports. In addition, the mid-2012 models also have an **HDMI** port: [MacBook Pro on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro).

And for the monitor, I'd guess you probably have a VGA connector. But it could also be DVI, HDMI, or something else (post a picture?).

Anyway, you'll probably need an adapter to connect your monitor. I'd suggest http://www.monoprice.com/.